# CKEDIOTR Mentions - Highlight Selected Name

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, mention

I am using CKEDITOR in my project with mentions plugin.

My requirement is when the content of CKEDITOR is saved I have to send a notification to mentioned user with the CKEDITOR content. It is working as expected except for this particular case.

- A user is selected from the dropdown.
- After selection the part of the selected user name is removed.

One the user has been selected from the dropdown the name is shown as like `@Anadi Chakraborty'. **Is it possible to show the user as it shows in JIRA?**

[image]

For the above case the entire mentioned user will be removed while back space is pressed.
I have tried with the config.outputtemplate but it does not work.

Code:

html:

```
<div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom:0;">
    <textarea class="form-control" id="wotxtcomments" rows="1" style="margin-bottom:1rem;" placeholder="Add a comment…"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-blue mobBttn" id="btnsavecommands" style="cursor:pointer; float:left; margin-right:10px;" value="save">&nbsp;Save</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-blue mobBttn" id="commandCancel" style="cursor:pointer; float:left;">&nbsp;Cancel</button>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Js:

```
 function LoadEditor() {
    for (name in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        CKEDITOR.instances[name].destroy(true);
    }
    CKEDITOR.config.mentions = [{
        feed: function (options, callback) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                    if (xhr.status == 200) {
                        callback(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
                    } else {
                        callback([]);
                    }
                }
            };
            xhr.open('GET', '/WorkOrderNew/GetMentionList?searchText=' + encodeURIComponent(options.query));
            xhr.send();
        },
        minChars: 0,
        itemTemplate: '<li data-id="{id}"><span class="userBadge">{type}</span>{name}</li>',
        outputTemplate: '<a style="color:red;" href={type}>{name}</a>'//'<span class="m-badge m-badge-grid-cell m-badge--green m-badge--wide">gsgsjgjs</span>'

    }];
    CKEDITOR.replace('wotxtcomments', {
        extraPlugins: 'mentions',
        toolbar: [
            { name: 'basicstyles', items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList'] }
        ],
        on:
        {
            instanceReady: function (ev) {
                this.focus();
            }
        }
    });
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to know my understanding is correct

If you have a selection with mentioned name it was automatically deleted right?

Comment: No..if I press back space the entire name should be deleted.

Comment: can you try like this after clicking delete key
`$(editor.getSelection().getStartElement().$).cloest('a').remove()`

Comment: Do you know how get the mentioned users from ckEditor?